# How to handle empty strings with class validators in TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, validation, typeorm

I want to create users from my Postman, I want to test my API endpoints, as it stands, it is possible to create a user if I pass something like "  " as a value for the name column, how can I handle that in TypeORM? I don't know any class validator. My Dto file is below:

import { IsNotEmpty, IsString } from 'class-validator';

```
export class CreateRoomUserDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  public name: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  public room_interest: string;    
  
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  public occupation: string;

}
```

This  is the entity file below

```
@import { IsNotEmpty } from 'class-validator';
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { RoomUser } from '@/interfaces/room-user.interface';

Entity()
export class RoomUserEntity implements RoomUser {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  room_interest: string;

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  occupation: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column()
  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below solves the problem, however, it is only able to catch the error if it is an empty array with just white space but it is not able to do anything if there's a white space at the beginning and/or the end of the string.

```
export class CreateRoomUserDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @Transform(({ value }: TransformFnParams) => value?.trim())
  public name: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @Transform(({ value }: TransformFnParams) => value?.trim())
  public room_interest: string;    
  
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  @Transform(({ value }: TransformFnParams) => value?.trim())
  public occupation: string;

}
```